# Facebook Open Graph Debugger Error

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am new to programming and have tried to make a facebook app with open graph beta tutorial. I have done exactly as described in the tutorial but when i try to use the debug tool it gives me an error:

> Extraneous Property:  Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:app_id.

I have noticed and searched that its doing this because the tag needs to be `<fb:app_id>`. I checked my file it says fb:app_id only, but the raw data that pulls up on the debug tool shows

> meta property="og:app_id" content="267029796703617"

even though i have changed and uploaded with fb:app_id.
I have checked my page several times and tried some possible solutions but have had no success. Can someone help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for sometime i made some changes to my objects and actions. What I did was added the image source in both object and action and things worked. If anyone has any other solution please post your answer as well.